# browsers won't download entire javascript file

Tags: reactjs, flask, webpack

I'm trying out webpack and reactjs for the first time and seem to be having some issues on the browser side.

When using Chrome I get:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/js/scripts.min.js 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

When I go to url `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/js/scripts.min.js` in the browser it doesn't download the entire `scripts.min.js` file.

Firefox seems to have the same issue by giving me `The connection was reset`.  However Microsoft Edge doesn't have the issue at all.

Currently i'm using `Flask` development web server but I'm also getting the same issue when using `gunicore`.

Here is the output from running `webpack`:

```
Hash: 6a5e4d31211a54d39531
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 6577ms
         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
scripts.min.js  1.89 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 172 hidden modules
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
  devtool: debug ? 'inline-sourcemap' : null,
  entry: './js-src/scripts.js',
  watch: true,
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.js?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)|(bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/src/wwwroot/static/js'),
    publicPath: '/static/js',
    filename: 'scripts.min.js'
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};`
```

Here is my `reactjs` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <h1>This is a test!</h1>
      );
  }
}

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<Layout/>, app);
```

Now if I run it with `NODE_ENV=production webpack` which causes the production plugins to be added I never get the error.  Here is the output from adding `NODE_ENV=production webpack`:

```
Hash: 7cef10c1a8547cfe93ca
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 3804ms
         Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
scripts.min.js  372 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 172 hidden modules

WARNING in scripts.min.js from UglifyJs
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js:97,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:136,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js:36,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:91,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:981,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:265,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:285,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable Transaction [../~/react/lib/ReactServerUpdateQueue.js:18,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js:54,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js:56,0]
```

Now I can also run it without production(just `webpack`) and always add plugin `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),` and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Part of `webpack.config.js` with just plugins part:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
```

The `webpack` output:

```
Hash: 6a5e4d31211a54d39531
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 4475ms
         Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
scripts.min.js  2.77 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 172 hidden modules

WARNING in scripts.min.js from UglifyJs
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js:136,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponentTree.js:97,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js:981,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:265,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js:285,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js:91,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/ReactNodeTypes.js:36,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable Transaction [../~/react/lib/ReactServerUpdateQueue.js:18,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js:54,0]
Condition always true [../~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js:56,0]
```

Anyone know the root cause of this issue?

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

I made a change to my `webpack.config.js`.  I changed devtool line:
from `devtool: debug ? 'inline-sourcemap' : null,` to `devtool: debug ? 'source-map' : null,` and the `webpack` output is:

```
Hash: 6a5e4d31211a54d39531
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 2206ms
             Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    scripts.min.js  742 kB       0  [emitted]  main
scripts.min.js.map  864 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 172 hidden modules
```

Now I still get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in Chrome but it seems to work in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: It's not being caused by Webpack's `watch` mode that rebuilds the file just when the browser happens to be downloading it?

Comment: No, not running in `watch` mode.  My work flow is 1) Make js change 2) Run webpack 3) After webpack completes, run my dev server 4) Refresh browser.  Most of the time it's a good 10+ seconds between webpack completing and refreshing the page.